# Python data class that is a mixture of dict and namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to create a data class that is strongly typed, and behaves both like a `namedtuple` and `dict`.

It should check the data types of the variables used to initialize it, and should support indexing in the style of sequences, therefore it should also be iterable and support type casting to `list`. It should also support retrieving values of the fields by using the field as attributes, in this regard it acts like a namedtuple.

However it should also support indexing in the style of mappings, by using the field names as keys, so it should be able to type cast to `dict` and JSON serializable.

I asked a question on StackOverflow when I almost finished my code, but it got closed for being unfocused. Now I have finished writing it, but I really don't know if this is a bad idea. I intend to use the data class to hold data retrieved from an SQLite3 database, where each row corresponds to an instance of the class, to make the results of queries strongly typed. And there are literally millions of rows in the database.

I also wanted to make it immutable, but I only partly succeeded doing so.

My code:

```
import json
import time
from json import JSONEncoder
from typing import Any, Deque, Generator, Iterable, Mapping
script_start = time.time()


def json_default(self, obj):
    return getattr(obj.__class__, "__json__", json_default.default)(obj)
json_default.default = JSONEncoder().default

JSONEncoder.default = json_default

NoneType = type(None)
Network_Fields = (
    ('slash', str),
    ('start_integer', int),
    ('end_integer', int),
    ('start_string', str),
    ('end_string', str),
    ('count', int),
    ('ASN', (int, NoneType)),
    ('country_code', (str, NoneType)),
    ('is_anonymous_proxy', bool),
    ('is_anycast', bool),
    ('is_satellite_provider', bool),
    ('bad', bool)
)

Network_Main_Fields = (
    'slash', 'start_string',
    'end_string', 'ASN',
    'country_code', 'bad'
)

class DotDictTuple:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.__dict__['_values'] = []
        if args:
            assert not kwargs
            data = args if len(args) != 1 else args[0]
            self.from_dict(data) if isinstance(data, dict) else self.from_list(data)
        else:
            assert kwargs
            self.from_dict(kwargs)
    
    def from_list(self, sequence: Iterable) -> None:
        assert len(sequence) == self.__class__._field_count
        for item, (field, datatype) in zip(sequence, self.__class__._fields):
            assert isinstance(item, datatype)
            self.__dict__[field] = item
            self._values.append(item)
    
    def from_dict(self, mapping: Mapping) -> None:
        assert len(mapping) == self.__class__._field_count
        for field, datatype in self.__class__._fields:
            assert isinstance((item := mapping.get(field)), datatype)
            self.__dict__[field] = item
            self._values.append(item)
    
    def __getitem__(self, key: int | str | slice) -> Any:
        return self._values[key] if isinstance(key, (int, slice)) else self.__dict__[key]
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(' + ', '.join(
            f'{field}={self[field]!r}' for field in self.__class__._main_fields
        )+')'
    
    def __full_repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(' + ', '.join(
            f'{field}={self[field]!r}' for field in self.__class__._field_list
        )+')'
    
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.__class__._field_count
    
    def __iter__(self) -> Generator:
        yield from self._values
    
    def __json__(self) -> dict:
        return {k: self.__dict__[k] for k in self.keys()}
    
    def values(self) -> tuple:
        return self._values
    
    def keys(self) -> tuple:
        return self.__class__._field_list
    
    def items(self) -> list:
        return [(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in self.keys()]


class Network(DotDictTuple):
    _field_count = len(Network_Fields)
    _fields = Network_Fields
    _main_fields = Network_Main_Fields
    _field_list = [k for k, _ in Network_Fields]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super(Network, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__['_values'] = tuple(self._values)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.slash
    
    def __setattr__(self, *_, **__) -> None:
        raise TypeError
    
    __delattr__ = __setattr__
```

Example usage

```
Network(['1.0.0.0/24', 16777216, 16777471, '1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.255', 256, 13335, 'AU', False, True, False, False])
Network(slash='1.0.0.0/24', start_integer=16777216, end_integer=16777471, start_string='1.0.0.0', end_string='1.0.0.255', count=256, ASN=13335, country_code='AU', is_anonymous_proxy=False, is_anycast=True, is_satellite_provider=False, bad=False)
Network(*['1.0.0.0/24', 16777216, 16777471, '1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.255', 256, 13335, 'AU', False, True, False, False])
Network('1.0.0.0/24', 16777216, 16777471, '1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.255', 256, 13335, 'AU', False, True, False, False)
Network({'slash': '1.0.0.0/24', 'start_integer': 16777216, 'end_integer': 16777471, 'start_string': '1.0.0.0', 'end_string': '1.0.0.255', 'count': 256, 'ASN': 13335, 'country_code': 'AU', 'is_anonymous_proxy': False, 'is_anycast': True, 'is_satellite_provider': False, 'bad': False})

network = Network(['1.0.0.0/24', 16777216, 16777471, '1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.255', 256, 13335, 'AU', False, True, False, False])
network.ASN
network['ASN']
network[0]
network['slash']
len(network)
list(network)
dict(network)
for i in network:
    print(i)
```

All the examples work.

But I really don't think my solution is concise and elegant. How to make it more Pythonic?

---

If I didn't make it clear, the base class is intended to be subclassed by a few other classes, the bulk of the logic should be implemented in the base class, while the subclasses have different numbers of fields and type requirements.

---

My idea is to only use the SQLite3 database as a way to persist the data between sessions of the program, in other words serializing the data.

I have millions of rows in the data, and `json` is terribly inefficient for this purpose, and is `csv`. I need a binary serialization library, but `pickle` is unsafe and more importantly a pkl generated by one Python version cannot be used by another version.

I don't know what other alternative there is. I intend to retrieve all rows from the database upfront when the class to query it initializes, so all data is in memory, because I have tested that retrieving a single value from the database using where takes milliseconds, I need to do it repeatedly.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you built on top of standard [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) rather than hand-rolled your own. You also mention these represent database rows, and [sqlalchemy also already has integrations with dataclasses](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html).

Comment: This is a bad idea: `assert isinstance((item := mapping.get(field)), datatype)`. When someone runs the code with the optimization flags, -O or -OO, `assert` statements are removed, so `item` won't be assigned, which could lead to various exceptions or worse, wrong data from `item` defined in an outer scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dislike that you can't discern the fields/attributes of `class Network` from looking at it. You need to look at `Network_Fields`, which in this case is not near where `class Network` is defined.

As @Kache suggested, it might make sense to try to use `dataclasses`. We just need to add some methods to get the desired behaviors.

#### dataclass with a base class

One way to do that us to use a base class to add the methods. The difficulty is that the class isn't a "dataclass" until after the `@dataclass` decorator processes the class. So any base class or meta class can't use functions like `dataclasses.fields()` to find all the fields in the dataclass. This can be handled by testing if the class is fully initialized when an instance method is called. For example:

```
class Base:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            return getattr(self, key)  
        
        else:
            if not hasattr(self.__class__, '_name'):
                self.__class__._name = [f.name for f in fields(self)]

            if isinstance(key, slice):
                return [getattr(self, name) for name in self.__class__._name[key]]
            
            else:
                return getattr(self, self.__class__._name[key])    

            
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__class__._name)
        
        
@dataclass
class Bar(Base):
    field1: str
    field2: int
    field3: bool
```

When an attempt is made to access a field of `Bar` using an index or a slice, the class is checked for a `_name` attribute. If it doesn't exist one is created containing a list of the dataclass fields in order. The enables one to get the field names corresponding to the index or slices. It works but seems a little "hacky".

#### use a decorator

Another option is to use a decorator to add the methods. Because, the `dataclass` decorator has already processed the class, the `dataclasses.fields()` function can be used to get information about the fields, such as names, types, defaults, etc.

```
# needed because None may be a valid value for a dataclass field
SENTINEL = object()

def makedictuple(cls):
    """decorator to add tuple-like and dict-like methods to a dataclass
    """
    
    # list mapping indexes to field names
    cls._name = [f.name for f in fields(cls)]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, str):
            return getattr(self, key)  
        
        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            return [getattr(self, name) for name in cls._name[key]]
            
        else:
            return getattr(self, cls._name[key])    
        
    cls.__getitem__ = __getitem__
    
    
    def from_sequence(sequence):
        "a classmethod to construct cls from a sequence"
        
        for arg, field in zip(sequence, fields(cls)):
            if not isinstance(arg, field.type):
                raise TypeError(f"'{arg}' not of type '{field.type}'.")
        
        return cls(*sequence)
    
    cls.from_sequence = from_sequence

    def from_dict(mapping):
        "a classmethod to construct cls from a mapping"
        
        for field in fields(cls):
            value = mapping.get(field.name, SENTINEL)
            if value != SENTINEL and not isinstance(value, field.type):
                raise TypeError(f"Field ''{field.name}' value '{value}' not of type '{field.type}'.")
        
        return cls(**mapping)
        
    cls.from_dict = from_dict
    
    cls.__len__ = lambda self: len(cls._name)
    cls.__iter__ = lambda self: (getattr(self, name) for name in self._name)
    cls.keys = lambda self: asdict(self).keys()
    cls.values = lambda self: asdict(self).values()
    cls.items = lambda self: asdict(self).items()
    
    return cls
```

Used like this:

```
NoneType = type(None)

@makedictuple
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Network:
    prefix: str
    start_integer: int
    end_integer: int
    start_string: str
    end_string: str
    count: int
    ASN: (int , NoneType)
    country_code: (str, NoneType)
    is_anonymous_proxy: bool
    is_anycast: bool
    is_satellite_provider: bool
    bad: bool
```

Everything is defined in one place, and the `@dataclass` decorator creates `__init__`, `__repr__`, `as_dict` and other methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
    ('slash', str),
```

Hmmm, interesting name for a field that looks like `"10.1.2.0/24"`.
Consider calling it by its conventional name of `prefix`
(or perhaps `cidr`, `cidr_prefix`, or `ip_prefix`).

Consider offering one or two fixed-width output methods for it,
so we get "010.001.002.000/24", or hex "0a010200/24".
That would facilitate producing text which has a sensible sort order.

---

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
```

nit: `mypy` already knows that ctor returns `None`.

---

```
            assert isinstance((item := mapping.get(field)), datatype)
```

As @RootTwo observes, evaluating an `assert` for side effects on `item`
doesn't make sense.
Prefer `if ... raise ...`

---

```
    def __full_repr__(self) -> str:
```

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you spell it `_full_repr`.
Yes, I get the parallel construction for the `repr()` method.
But there's no corresponding protocol to invoke this,
so the dunder is misleading.

---

```
        return self.__class__._field_count
```

Maybe there's documentation value in this?
But consider using the more conventional spelling of

```
        return self._field_count
```

The larger issue is that `DotDictTuple`
lacks several attributes including `_field_count`,
so it should probably be marked
[abstract](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).

---

```
            self._values.append(item)
            ...
            self._values.append(item)
            ...
    def values(self) -> tuple:
        return self._values
```

Those first two lines make me sad.
(Also, invoking `from_{list,dict}` twice leads to a bad result.)

Couldn't that final line derive the needed values
by walking through dictionary entries?

---

```
        self.__dict__['_values'] = tuple(self._values)
```

I don't understand this line.

If a tuple is desired, shouldn't the parent class
have tuplified the `list` when all values became known?
I'm objecting to using different type in the parent & child classes.

Also, this further motivates deriving values from dict keys.

---

```
Network(['1.0.0.0/24', 16777216, 16777471, '1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.255', 256, 13335, 'AU', False, True, False, False])
...
Network(*['1.0.0.0/24', 16777216, 16777471, '1.0.0.0', '1.0.0.255', 256, 13335, 'AU', False, True, False, False])
```

I don't understand what's desirable about supporting both those forms.
Pick one, the latter. Delete the former.

```
Network(slash='1.0.0.0/24', start_integer=16777216, end_integer=16777471, start_string='1.0.0.0', end_string='1.0.0.255', count=256, ASN=13335, country_code='AU', is_anonymous_proxy=False, is_anycast=True, is_satellite_provider=False, bad=False)
...
Network({'slash': '1.0.0.0/24', 'start_integer': 16777216, 'end_integer': 16777471, 'start_string': '1.0.0.0', 'end_string': '1.0.0.255', 'count': 256, 'ASN': 13335, 'country_code': 'AU', 'is_anonymous_proxy': False, 'is_anycast': True, 'is_satellite_provider': False, 'bad': False})
```

Similarly, replace the 2nd form with `Network(**{'slash': ...`

---

```
    def __setattr__(self, *_, **__) -> None:
        raise TypeError
```

Kudos! I like the whole immutable thing.

---

You mentioned sqlite.
But I didn't notice any
[SqlAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html#integration-with-dataclasses-and-attrs)
integration.
Do follow @Kache's advice.
I recommend you code up some unit tests that ask SqlAlchemy to
store / retrieve rows in a sqlite table.
Pay attention to what that client code is telling you.
If it's inconvenient or clunky to write,
then refine your Public API to make it more convenient.
Note that within a `for row in query:` block,
it is common enough to ask for `row._asdict()`,
or even: `for row in map(dict, query):`

---

This code achieves its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks
on this codebase.